# How to sort and group data in request?

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, subquery, greatest-n-per-group

I have got table.

```
ID       section_name     purchaseNumber    docPublishDate  parsing_status
88940   notifications   0373200124515000035   2015-02-27       null
88939   notifications   0373200124515000035   2015-02-29       null
88938   notifications   0373200124515000034   2015-02-27       null
88687   notifications   0373100064615000120   2015-02-28       null
88937   notifications   0373100064615000120   2015-02-27       null
89122   notifications   0373100064615000120   2015-02-27       null
88936   notifications   0373200124515000032   2015-02-27       null
88988   notifications   0373100064615000120   2015-03-02       null
88696   notifications   0373100066915000038   2015-02-27       null
88963   notifications   0373200174515000013   2015-02-27       null
```

It have some duplicates in `purchaseNumber`. I need select from this table only newest records for processing.
In other words I need to:

1. group elements by `purchaseNumber`
2. sort them by `docPublishDate` and select newest.
3. if any of elements in group is have status `parsing_status` `true` (suppose it was newest from step 2) any elements SHOULD NOT be returned.

After processing `parsing_status` flag is changing to `true`.

`docPublishDate` - TimeStamp

The items with old dates should not be selected if at last one newest was processed.
I tried to do some grouping. But code simply return me all data:

```
SELECT 
  "id", "section_name", "purchaseNumber", "docPublishDate", "parsing_status"
  FROM "xml_files" WHERE parsing_status IS NULL GROUP BY "purchaseNumber", "id", "section_name", "docPublishDate", "parsing_status" ORDER BY "docPublishDate" DESC
```

Comment: It is unclear wich result you want. In your sample data, all rows have `null` values in column `parsing_status`: your query would not return any row. Please provide representative sample data, along with the result that you want.

Comment: @GMB, I have added more explanation to post. And fixed table.

Comment: Can you please share the expected outcome too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you want the latest row per purchase, excepted those whose parsing status is true. One option uses `distinct on` in a subquery to get the latest element, and then filters in an outer query:

```
select *
from (
    select distinct on (purchasenumber) x.*
    from xml_files x
    order by purchasenumber, docpublishdate desc
) x
where parsing_status is distinct from true
```

Comment: I am getting error: ```operator does not exist: character varying = boolean```

Comment: @DmitryBubnenkov: if `parsing_status` is of a string datatype and not a boolean, just change the `where` clause: `where parsing_status is distinct from 'true'`

Comment: Thanks. What `x.*` is doing?

Comment: @DmitryBubnenkov: that's just a table alias.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE T
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM YOUR_TABLE TT
                    WHERE T.PURCHASENUMBER = TT.PURCHASENUMBER
                      AND (TT.DOCPUBLISHDATE > T.DOC_PUBLISHDATE 
                           OR T.PARSINGSTATUS = 'true') );
```

Comment: Could you explain how it's work? I am about subquery

Comment: It returns the records from your table having max `DOCPUBLISHDATE` for each `PURCHASENUMBER` but it will not give the result if for same `PURCHASENUMBER` there is one of the record having `PARSINGSTATUS = 'true'`

Comment: Ans what about speed? It's taking a lot of time even not for very big table